# Simulation of Arcs/ Arch , Matlab (Concept)

Tags: matlab, geometry

Please see attached image[image]

In image one can see two arc(blue &green) and red lines connecting them. This gives us surface (I think its rounded arch, but please correct me if it's wrong).

My question is how to simulate this structure.

1-how can I have function f(x,y,z) of this structure

2-how to get line(Arch surface) intersection

3-points on it?

*In short, I want to get points (x,y,z) on this structure from a given stand point/view point.e.g.,P=[19,-62,-1.2]*

[image]

Matlab code would be more helpfull.

**Some more info:**

Points on 1st curve

```
p2 = [17.9463,-59.7586,-1.0200]; % start [x,y,z]
p0 = [19.1163,-58.5886,-1.0200]; % center
p1 = [20.2863,-59.7586,-1.0200]; % End
```

Points on 2nd curve

```
p4 = [17.9463,-59.7586,-1.78]; 
p0_ = [19.1163,-58.5886,-1.78]; 
p3 = [20.2863,-59.7586,-1.78];
```

radius:
r=1.17;

Any idea?

Comment: your question is a bit vague. What do you mean by "simulating the structure"? Do you want a parametric representation of it, as a function `f(x,y)`? Why is this question Matlab related?

Comment: much better now. Do you have 1D functions of blue and green lines? It looks from image that surface is half a cylinder. Is that so?

Comment: well big questions the ones you are asking! I'll try to gather a bit information

Comment: @user31177 Computing a projection is a more complex problem than the one you originally described. The projection changes as you change the viewing angle, so what is your desired viewing angle? Are you staring straight at the center of the cylinder or at another point?

Answer (score 2):

Obtaining an exact function from a drawing of a curve is a somewhat imprecise task. However, you can still make a good approximation if you make assumptions and approximations.

Let's assume that this a half-cylindrical shape. The circular cross-section is in the x-z plane, meaning that the 3-D curve is:

> F(x, y, z) = (*x*-*x*<sub>0</sub>)<sup>2</sup> + (*z*-*z*<sub>0</sub>)<sup>2</sup> = *r*<sup>2</sup>

Where *x*<sub>0</sub> and *z*<sub>0</sub> are the center coordiantes and *r* is the radius.

I assume that the left axis in your plot is the y-axis, and the z-axis is on the right. From what I can tell, their approximate values are:

> *x*<sub>0</sub> ≈ 19.1
>   *z*<sub>0</sub> ≈ -59.6
>   *r* ≈ 1.2
>   *y* seems to vary between -1 and -1.7

You can use [`meshgrid`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/meshgrid.html) and [`surf`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/surf.html) to easily produce a 3-D plot:

```
r = 1.2;
x0 = 19.1;
z0 = -59.6;
[X, Y] = meshgrid(17.9:0.05:20.3, -1.7:0.05:-1);
Z = z0 + abs(sqrt(r ^ 2 - (X - x0) .^ 2));
surf(X, Y, Z)
```

Note two things:

1. I've set the resolution to 0.05 on both the x-axis and the y-axis.
2. I've applied `abs` on the result of `sqrt` to eliminate any unwanted complex results.

The result should be something like this:

[image]

Comment: @ Eithan T, thanx a lot. Its my fault. I should make question more clear. MY question is  that I want to simulate (x,y,z) on this surface from given stand point/ view point.

Comment: @user31177 What do you mean "from a given viewpoint"? After you create the figure, you can use the data-cursor tool to click on the surface anywhere and obtain its coordinates.

Comment: @ Eithan T, thanx again for your reply. Consider that you are standing on [0,0,0] and view this structure. Now using line of sight, you put regular points on this structure. Its normal in computer games

Comment: @user31177 I'm still having troube following you. What does "put regular points" mean? Do you just want the object rotated and viewed from (0, 0, 0) or do you want to project this object on a 2-D plane?

Comment: @ Eithan T, projection of points. please see edited question

Comment: @ Eithan T, I need two things for this task 1-  point of intersection of line of sight and this structure 2- Algorithm to check if point is on the structure or outside. A similar thing for a plane 1-http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line-plane_intersection.